# application/x-www-form-urlencode returned messy result using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I didn't add this line in my ajax and I saw null return in my console

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

above line work (at least I'm seeing result), but the result is a mess, it even contain html tag. In my php I did data scraping with php simple dom parser (a library), and with jquery and css.

I even tried to do like this, which I put the $_post after the scrapping logic

```
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
//etc etc here
<?php 
    if( isset($_POST['data']) ){
    echo $result;

} ?>
```

how to return on the the $result to my ajax callback? I also tried text/plain-text in header request, it returned null.

Comment: are you sure youre exit() ing after the echo? or you leave the entire HTML rendering as well?

Comment: I'm seeing even the <script src='jquery'> thing appear in my ajax callback.